# How to find number of snapshots for a vm using powershell

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am new to PowerShell scripting. I am trying to get number of snapshots have been created for a VM. I am able to get snapshots information of the VM's using the below command.

```
get-vm Test_sub | Get-Snapshot
```

It is giving complete information but is there any way I can count the number of snapshots?

Thanks,
Sasikumar.

Comment: Assuming that returns an array just save it and use `$arr.Length`?

Answer (score 2):

If Get-Snapshot returns one output for each snapshot then use Measure-Object (alias Measure) to see the count e.g.:

```
get-vm Test_sub | Get-Snapshot | Measure
```

If you need the value in a script then:

```
$count = (get-vm Test_sub | Get-Snapshot).length
```